# If $n$ is a natural number, then what are the possible values(s) of gcd $(n+1, 2-n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $n$ is a natural number, then what are the possible **values(s)** of gcd $(n+1, 2-n)$?

There are six options: $1,2,3,4,5,6$

I think the answer is $1$

Comment: Consider $n=2$.

Comment: They are asking *what* the possible options are, meaning that you are choosing which of those $6$ values is possible. There will be multiple answers.

Answer (score 5):

$gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,a+b)$

$gcd (n+1,2−n)=gcd(n+1,3)\in\{1,3\}$

Answer (score 2):

If $p|n+1$ and $p|2-n$, then $p|n+1+2-n=3$, thus $p=1$ or $p=3$.

The case $p=3$ can happen with $n=2+3k$.

For other value of $n$, the gcd is of course 1.